# How do we create Payload in Jmeter using Groovy Scripting

Tags: arrays, groovy, jmeter, payload

How do we create Payload in Jmeter using Groovy Scripting in format

```json
[
  {
    "test": 123,
    "number": "welcome"
  },
  {
    "test": 123,
    "number": "welcome"
  },
  {
    "test": 123,
    "number": "welcome"
  }
]
```

Tried below code but it has name for array which should not be there in above format.

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def listS = new JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
def jsonBuilder = new JsonBuilder()

jsonBuilder {

    "list" lists.collect {
        [
            carrierid: vars.get('carrierid'),
            carrierType: vars.get('carrierType'),
            cou: vars.get('ean'),
            position: vars.get('position'),
            taskId: vars.get('taskId'),
            OQ: vars.get('OQ'),       
        ]
    }
}

vars.put('requestBody', jsonBuilder.toPrettyString())
log.info('Generated body: ' + vars.get('requestBody'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass required object or array as a parameter to JsonBuilder constructor

```
def jsonBuilder = new JsonBuilder(
  lists.collect {
    ...
  }
)

vars.put('requestBody', jsonBuilder.toPrettyString())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want particular that payload which is in your question:

```
def payload = []

1.upto(3, {
    payload.add([test: 123, number: 'welcome'])
})

vars.put('requestBody', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
log.info('Generated body: ' + vars.get('requestBody'))
```

In short:

- [JSON Object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) - is a [Map](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html)
- [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) - is a [List](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html)

[image]

More information:

- [JsonBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)